# Is Spatial Audio used while listening to music on AirPods Pro?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, airpods

When I'm listening to music from my iPhone (iOS 14) with my AirPods Pro, I don't want Spatial Audio on because I don't always have my phone near me - will this affect my audio?

I prefer to leave the setting on, instead of toggling it when I listen to music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spatial Audio](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211775) is only used for video:

> Spatial audio with dynamic head tracking brings a theater-like surround-sound experience to the **movie or video** you're watching...

You can confirm if the content you're listening to supports spatial audio by toggling it off and on:

[image][image]

Comment: Most music is distributed in stereo, whereas most modern movies and tv shows are distributed with more audio tracks. But, if you explicitly add a surround sound track to your music library, I wonder if it would play with spatial audio. I'd certainly hope it would!

Comment: You mean like [DVD Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Audio) at @Wowfunhappy.  So, with respect to this answer, it's *not* limited to only video and yes, I would hope they would play it!